# How to concatename file names in Snakemake?

Tags: snakemake

I want to pass a series of files (e.g., `a`, `b`) to a program `prog` like: `prog a,b`.

Is there a way to do this in Snakemake?

My attempt is:

```
rule run_prog:
  input: "a", "b"
  output: "output"
  run: "prog {input}"
```

But the actual command Snakemake generated is `prog a b` instead of `prog a,b`.

Any solution to pass a comma concatenated file names to Snakemake?

Comment: `run: "prog {input[0]},{input[1]}"` ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands that works, is there a general solution, as there can be ~20 input files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join to convert the list of input file into a string. 
I think this would work as expected.:

```py
rule run_prog:
    input: "a", "b"
    output: "output"
    run: f"prog {','.join(input)}"
```

Comment: This works great. It works for `f"prog {','.join(input.variable)}"`  if I define `variable` under `input:` section. Can you explain why have to use `input[:]` instead of `input`?

Comment: Right, using `input` by itself is the same ! I edited my answer.